# How to set Object reference to instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, claims-based-identity, xunit, xunit.net

I'm writting Xunit test for the below controller. when ever i run my test i am getting this error

```
object reference is notset to an instance of an object
```

This is my test code

```
  [Fact]
    public async Task RegistrationTest()
    {
 ctrl = new AccountsControllers(context, userManager, jwtFactory, jwtoptions);
       ctrl.ModelState.AddModelError("x", "Model error");

        var mod = new RegistrationViewModel
        {
            Email = "johnmiller@sins.com"
        };
        IActionResult result = await ctrl.Register(mod);
       // Assert.Equal(mod.Email, moe);
        var viewresult = Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);

    }
```

However, I successfully create instances for context, usermanager

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options
                .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Inventory;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0"));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

        var con = new DefaultHttpContext();

        con.Features.Set<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>(new HttpAuthenticationFeature());

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(h => new HttpContextAccessor { HttpContext = con });

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();
        userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

I am not getting how to create for IJwtFactory and JwtIssuerOptions

This is my Accounts controller constructor

```
 public AccountsControllers(ApplicationContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
            IJwtFactory jwtFactory, IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtoptions)
    {
        appDbContext = context;

        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.jwtFactory = jwtFactory;
        jwtOptions = jwtoptions.Value;

        serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
    }
```

This is the Loginmethod inside the accounts controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel credentials)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);

        if (identity == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
        }
        var response = new
        {
            id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value,
           auth_token = await jwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken(credentials.UserName, identity),
            expires_in = (int)jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, serializerSettings);
        return new OkObjectResult(json);
    }
```

ClaimsIdentity

```
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentity(string userName, string password)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            // get the user to verifty
            var userToVerify = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);


            if (userToVerify != null)
            {

                // check the credentials  
              if (await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password))
               {
                   return await Task.FromResult(jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(userName, userToVerify.Id));
                }

            }

        }

        return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to mock out all your many dependencies and you're apparently missing something somewhere. Whenever you find yourself with more than a couple of dependencies you need to mock, that's a pretty clear sign you're in integration testing territory.

In general, any time you're testing a controller action, you're integration testing. Although they *look* like methods on a class, there's so much that needs to happen as part of the request pipeline to actually make them function correctly, you can't really test them without an actual request. In particular, things like creating an `HttpContext` with an authenticated user and such doesn't happen outside of a request pipeline. You can technically mock all this as well, but again, that's just more dependencies that you're having to manually supply and more opportunities to create tests that fail because the setup isn't correct and not because anything is actually *wrong*.

Since that's the case, actually do a true integration test and utilize `TestServer`. You can feed it your `Startup` class so all the services get registered and injected as they should, then you simply make a request and verify the response object. For mocking things like your database connection, you should set up a "Test" environment and configure that in your Startup.cs to use things like the in-memory EF database provider. Then, you can specify that your `TestServer` should use that "Test" environment, and you're good to go. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for more information.